# AWS ELB - Service A can't connect to Service B within same Security Group

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I'm trying to make a simple REST request from Service A (Spring Boot) to Service B (Node.js) within the same VPC.

If I configure the Node.js Security Group to "All TCP" and "0.0.0.0/0" it works when I hit my `http://xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com/api` endpoint from Service A.

However, when I try to limit Service B traffic to within my VPC only, Service A can no longer reach it.

I've tried two different approaches:

1. Service A and Service B share the same Security Group and it allows inbound traffic to itself.
2. Service A is part of a Security Group, Service B's separate Security Group allows inbound traffic from this SG.

Neither of these configurations work.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: I think the service B is public api. When service A tries to access B, B only recognizes A's public address

Comment: It's not a public API though, it's a service within our own VPC.

Comment: how do you say that it's not public facing service?, Your elastic beans talk VPC configuration should be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbkIk.jpg. `Elbvisibility` property should be set to `internal` if its an internal Service.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Public IP address range(s) of the datacentre and the service you are using from this page, and allow SG rule for that IP address Range(s) that should do the job.